# python lexer appends to array only 1st keyword

Tags: python, lexer

I have created a lexer and in my file I have many keywords, but python appends only the 1st

here is the lexer code:

```
KEYWORDS = ['dessert', 'if', 'else', 'pack', 'class', 'fn']
def tokenize(self):
    self.letters = list(self.content)
    self.letters = list(filter(self.__filter_letters, self.letters))
    tok = ''

    self.tokens = []
    for l in self.letters:
        tok += str(l)
        if tok in KEYWORDS:
            self.tokens += [tok]
            tok = ''

    return self.tokens
```

and this is my file content:

```
pack random

fn main(){
    dessert 'i'
    let args = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for x in args{
        say(x)
    }
}
```

the output is `['pack']`

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but the normal way to add to a list is with `self.tokens.append(tok)`

Comment: there is not any deiferrence

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is correct? You would get this problem if the `return` statement were indented inside the `if`.

Comment: I said it wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: yes it it returning, if it wouldnt that i would not see the result

Comment: You would see that result if it were indented at the same level as `self.tokens += [tok]`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can see how you're creating `self.letters`.

Comment: i tried its not becouse of indentions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219557/discussion-between-some-see-a-pen-i-see-a-harpoon-and-barmar).

Comment: After successfully parsing `pack`, the next few characters are `random` - that's not one of your tokens, or the prefix of any of your tokens, so you will keep on adding letters to `tok` forever without ever finding another token.